# PHP 5.4.16, pdo_mysql 5.6.31, MySQL community server 5.7.17-log - Integers always quoted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I went through all of the questions regarding MySQL and the PDO driver enclosing integer values in single quotes. Some of the questions related specifically to the [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) function. The other ones in regard to the [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) quoting integers were answered either by suggesting turning off emulation mode or specifying `PDO::PARAM_INT` for the bound parameter. In my case neither of those result in the desired behavior i.e. unquoting the integers.

```
$query = 'UPDATE `table` SET `cX`=:cX WHERE `id`=:id';
$db->prepare($query);
$db->bindParam(":cX", 700, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->bindParam(":id", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->execute();
```

Looking at the mysql general log this results in:

```
command_type: Query | argument: UPDATE `table` SET `cX`='700' WHERE `id`='1'
```

Turning off emulation mode has absolutely no effect on the end result either - it only affects the intermediate steps and PHP to MySQL communication mechanism.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$query = 'UPDATE `table` SET `cX`=:cX WHERE `id`=:id';
$db->prepare($query);
$db->bindParam(":cX", 700, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->bindParam(":id", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->execute();
```

This time the MySQL general log reads:

```
command_type: Prepare | argument: UPDATE `table` SET `cX`=? WHERE `id`=?
command_type: Close stmt
command_type: Execute | argument: UPDATE `table` SET `cX`='700' WHERE `id`='1'
```

So no matter what setup I use the integers always get enclosed in quotes. So my question is: Is there any way to get around this or is it already a standard and something that should be accepted as normal behavior?

Comment: I guess you did not reach this site https://phpdelusions.net/pdo  on your research.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile if you could point the OP to the relevant parts in that tutorial, your comment would be more helpful.

Comment: The suggested article doesn't answer what I guess would be the real question here - why $db->bindParam(":cX", 700, PDO::PARAM_INT); still doesn't unquote the integer values and what is the purpose of PDO::PARAM_INT for that matter because I see no difference whether I use it or not.